# Form of coordinate ring $\mathbb{C}[t]/I$ for $I$ ideal in $\mathbb{C}[t]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I am wondering what coordinate ring $\mathbb{C}[t]/I$ for $I=\langle t^2(3-t^2)\rangle$ looks like. For any cases with more than one variable, I can somewhat imagine the structure by using the fact that the coordinate ring encodes the structure of the zero set over the ideal $I$.

So far I have never thought about the case of one variable for which the zeros are a discrete point set in $\mathbb{C}$ by the fundamental theorem of algebra.
But if I take any $q\in \mathbb{C}[t]$ which is coprime with $p(t) = t^2(3-t^2)$ , i.e., no shared zeros, then $q\in \mathbb{C}[t]/I$ and I do not see how I can make a link with the zero set of $p$.

How can I imagine the algebraic geometry for polynomials in one variable?

Comment: With the induced reduced subscheme structure it’s literally that quotient ring no?

Comment: Saying $q\not\in I$ and saying $q\in\mathbb{C}[t]/I$ are different things. Elements of the quotient aren't polynomials; they're _equivalence classes_ of polynomials, just as elements of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ are equivalence classes of numbers. We often choose one representative of each equivalence class for convenience's sake (e.g., a polynomial of degree $\leq3$ for $\mathbb{C}[t]/I$, or a number in $\{0\ldots 3\}$ for $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$), but it's important to keep in mind that they're representatives for a large set of equivalent entities.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki yes, indeed, I thought that $p$ and $q$ coprime implied that I could choose $q$ as the representative of one equivalence class which is generally given by $q + hp$ for any $h$ in $\mathbb{C}[t]$.

Comment: @Chris unfortunately, I am not familiar with the topic at the level of your comment... sorry. Could you explain a bit more?